# Element height Attribute stored as a Variable in iReport

Tags: java, xml, jasper-reports, reporting, ireport

I have a table with detail cells like:

```
<jr:detailCell height="46" rowSpan="1">
```

I want to change the height, depending on the value of a Query. It works with the color like this:

```
<style name="parentInfoStyle">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[($V{LayerTwoID}==1)]]></conditionExpression>
        <style forecolor="#4D4D4F"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[($V{LayerTwoID}!=1)]]></conditionExpression>
        <style forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
```

But conditional styles don't seem to be working with height. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is impossible. You can use *JasperReports API* for building report dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround. Instead of directly changing the height, I checked the "Stretch With Overflow"
property of the textfields and scaled the contents of the table entries with \n's. Not a clean solution, but it works fine.